# Error while building APK Android Studio 2.2.3

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob

I am trying to generate a signed APK to test my app on a physical device. The app was working functionally before I tried to add the `Google AdMob` banner ad to my app. I keep getting this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzkf;
```

Here is my `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.coolappsforall.fartboard"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.0.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false;
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.6.0'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'

    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.4.0'
}
```

Not exactly sure what is causing the problem, if anyone knows, or if you need anything else, please let me know.

Thank you very much for your time and assistance in this matter.

Comment: You're using different versions of two Google Play Services libraries - 11.6.0 for ads and 8.4.0 for appindexing. What happens if you use the same version for both?

Answer (score 1):

This error happens when you have some classes that are overlapping from different libraries. Try to add this:

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

Comment: The same error occurs, and I ran the sync for the Gradle Files.

Comment: Clean the project. Another thing you can try is 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.6.0' and  'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.4.0' are both using same version number.

Answer (score 0):

```
// add line  multiDexEnabled true in defaultConfig

     defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.coolappsforall.fartboard"
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 25
            versionCode 2
            versionName "1.0.1"
    multiDexEnabled true
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }

//add below lines after closed bracts 

dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
```

// change compilesdk version
`compileSdkVersion 23`
and

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.6.1'
```

Comment: I am now getting this error: Error:(37, 1) A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find method dexOptions() for arguments [build_9vamyx76i2w0gaawj07n1azxo$_run_closure3@6602ad00] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have mix different version of Google Play Service dependencies. Hence you need to make them the same:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:11.6.0'
}
```